# Spring boot cucumber TestExecutionListener before database initalization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber-jvm

I want to create integration test with docker before cucumber test start. Inspired by: http://tech.asimio.net/2016/08/04/Integration-Testing-using-Spring-Boot-Postgres-and-Docker.html

But in my case the TestExecutionListener is not started before database initialization. I use Flyway for database migrations and it seems it tries to initialize first. For this a database connection required, which is not available, due the TestExecutionListener not being executed.

These are my classes:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"json:target/integration-cucumber.json"},
        features = "src/test/resources"
)
public class CucumberIntegration {
}
```

And my test class which I will be extended by the cucumber steps:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")
@TestExecutionListeners({
        DockerizedTestExecutionListener.class,
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class
})
public class SpringIntegrationTest {
}
```

When I change `@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)` to `@SpringBootTest` I see `DockerizedTestExecutionListener` being executed. Only it fails because it misses configuration from `Application.class`.

Anyone idea how to this with or without TestExecutionListener?

Comment: I'm the author of said post, the idea of using a Docker image with seed data was assuming database migrations / seeding data for each integration test  is more expensive than starting a Docker container. Why are you trying to accomplish with Cucumber and Flyway?

Comment: @ootero we already use cucumber for validating business logic. With this I also want to test the migration script (flyway) to catch issues with it in an early stage. Also for the a lot of feature files, spring is only booted once, so we wont have to migrate for each feature/scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because the `Cucumber.class` JUnit runner doesn't support `TestExecutionListeners`.

You might think that your test steps are executed by the `SpringRunner.class` JUnit runner, but they aren't.

The `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation on your `SpringIntegrationTest` class is basically useless here, since according to your post, your subclasses of `SpringIntegrationTest` contain Cucumber steps. However the `SpringRunner` expects JUnit `@Test` methods. Cucumber steps with `@Given`, `@When`, `@Then` etc. are ignored because `SpringRunner` doesn't know what to do with them.

What really executes your test steps is the `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` annotation in your `CucumberIntegration` class. The `Cucumber` runner, however, doesn't give a damn about the `TestExecutionListeners` annotation that your steps definition class inherits from `SpringIntegrationTest` because it doesn't support such a feature.

Execution listeners are a Spring-only feature. You won't be able to do what you want to do, at least not as long as you use Cucumber.